# Is it possible to have a different keyboard layout when capslock is on?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've been using xmodmap to switch my alt keys and currently i'm mapping capslock to home button.

What i'm trying to do is creating keybindings based on caps lock. so for example if caps lock is on and i press A key instead of printing a capitalized A it would for example emmit the left arrow key. So it's not like caps lock + A pressed at the same time, what i'm trying to achieve is having various key bindings when the caps lock is turned on and when it's off having a normal keyboard.

Is this possible somehow? I've been googling for a while couldn't find anything useful about the caps lock.

Answer (score 0):

**Changing keyboard layout with Caps Lock** works like this: First make sure you have your two keyboard layouts selected in `gnome-control-center` (aka 'Settings' in the dock):

[image: screenshot of gnome-control-center]

Install gnome-tweaks:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then start it:

```
gnome-tweaks
```

And find `Keyboards & Mouse`, click on `Additional Layout Options` and click on the arrow in front of `Switching to another layout`. Select the `Caps Lock` key (or any variant you'd like):

[image: screenshot of gnome-tweaks]

**Making your keys behave just the way you like** involves changing or making a symbols file (usually) in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`. A way to integrate this mapping in gnome is explained at the bottom on the page that describes (the history of) the [altgr-intl](https://www.choam.eu/altgr-intl/) layout.